# Why does static friction opposes force vector ...but kinetic friction opposes velocity vector?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, friction, drag

MY ANSWER- lets say a body is on rest and a force is applied thats slowly increasing ....the tiny bumps and groves between surfaces will apply a normal until the force is big enough to break through ...thats why static friction opposes force.

After the object is set in motion the bumps and valleys are constantly being broken and new ones come beneath the moving object ....so when lets say a new perpendicular to motion force is applied, there are no fixed bumps holding it back hence until the object starts to get some velocity in the perpendicular direction the constantly passingby bumps have no reason to produce an opposing force to the new perpendicular force ...its only when the object does move a little in this new direction(means it has velocity in new direction) the constantly passingby bumps start to also pass by in perpendicular direction ... and since these bumps are distributed uniformly in all directions, there is no bias in one direction so all it opposes is net velocity

Comment: The force vector and the velocity have the same direction?

Comment: @Eli after the new perpendicular force is applied thats not the case as the object is still moving forward but force is perpendicular